# Building the perfect number 28 with fractions

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

You are given the fractions $\frac{4}{3}, \frac{7}{3}, \frac{10}{3}, \frac{13}{3}.$

Use any operation of $+, -, *, /, ()$ to build 28 with those four fractions. You must use all four fractions exactly once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this

> $\frac{\frac{7}{3}}{\left(\frac{10}{3} - \frac{\frac{13}{3}}{\frac{4}{3}}\right)} = 28$

Comment: This is a perfect answer!