# Building the perfect number 28 with fractions - part2

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Here is a follow up of [Building the perfect number 28 with fractions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/92771/building-the-perfect-number-28-with-fractions)

You are given the fractions $\frac{3}{2}, \frac{5}{2}, \frac{7}{2}, \frac{11}{2}.$

Use any operation of $+, -, *, /, ()$ to build 28 with those four fractions. You must use all four fractions exactly once.

Comment: Funnily, with this one, it seems quite easy to achieve with just three of the fractions but seems very difficult with four.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps there is a slight trick to this one

> $\displaystyle\binom{\frac{11}{2} + \frac{5}{2}}{\frac{7}{2} - \frac{3}{2}} = \binom{8}{2} = 28$
>  where I've used () to denote a binomial coefficient.

Comment: again, well done, it looks like those are too easy for you!